# Concatenated column to be store in two different columns

Tags: mysql

I have a website and when customer register on it the data is stored in the admin panel, Now If you see in the below code at the first line emp_name and emp_ID is saving in a single column, and I want to save it in two different columns how to differentiate it.

```
$sql = "SELECT c.customer_id, CONCAT(c.emp_name, ' ', c.emp_ID) AS name,
 c.email, c.mobile_no, CONCAT(oca.address_1,oca.address_2) AS address, 
 oca.city, oca.postcode, occ.name as Country, c.ip,
IF( c.status = 1, 'Enabled','Disabled' ) AS status, 
IF( c.approved = 1, 'Yes', 'No' ) AS approved, c.date_added, cgd.name AS customer_group FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer c 
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "customer_group_description cgd ON (c.customer_group_id = cgd.customer_group_id) 
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "address oca ON (c.address_id=oca.address_id) 
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "country occ ON (oca.country_id=occ.country_id) 
WHERE cgd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
SELECT c.customer_id, 
       c.emp_id, 
       c.emp_name AS NAME, 
       c.email, 
       c.mobile_no, 
              Concat(oca.address_1,oca.address_2) AS address, 
       oca.city, 
       oca.postcode, 
       occ.NAME AS Country, 
       c.ip,IF( c.status = 1, 'Enabled', 'Disabled' ) as status, 
IF( c.approved = 1, 'Yes', 'No' ) AS approved, c.date_added, cgd.NAME AS customer_group FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer c LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "customer_group_description cgd ON (
  c.customer_group_id = cgd.customer_group_id 
) 
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "address oca ON ( 
  c.address_id=oca.address_id 
) 
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "country occ ON ( 
  oca.country_id=occ.country_id 
) 
WHERE cgd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'
```

MySQL [CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function is used to concatenate two or more strings to form a single string. This is why you see the data in a single column. Simply remove the function, if you want to show the data in separate columns.